# Applying onChange event on a div for all input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

Hello actually I have an div tag in which there are multiple form. What I want is to apply onChange event on the div for each input field. Present I am trying this

Applying form class to each form and getting onchange event

```
$('.form :input').change(function(e){
   console.log("Element changed");
});
```

But I am not able to get the info which field is changed and what is the updated value.

So can I apply it on the div itself? If not how can the get the field info which is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   $('.form :input').change(function(e){
      console.log($(e.target).attr('id'));
   });
});
```

here `e.target` is your current element which got the event of `change`.

---

As per your comment:

*How we can say which field is changed.*

you need to assign an unique identifier to all your `input type text`:

```
<input type='text' id='a'>
<input type='text' id='b'>
   ..................
```

then use this:

```
$('.form :input').change(function(e){
   $('#log').prepend('<p>Form changed ' + $(e.target).attr('id') + '</p>')
});
```

#### [A demo of your fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kNx8p/182/)

Comment: Please see if you can help me.

Comment: How we can say which field is changed.\

Comment: Its okay, glad that helped you.

Comment: last question how can we get the value from e

Comment: `$(e.target).val()` this will give you the value of current target element.